# Number of rows in table are equal to the results squared

Tags: php, mysql

I am in need of some assistance regarding table creation in PHP. In my code, my table is printing way too many times. For some reason, the output of the code is whatever the count of the number of results is ^2. So, if I have 4 results in the actual database, I have 16 results in the output. I would like to do a bit more research before posting in the forums, but I am new to php and have no idea where to begin.

```
//Count the number of rows returned
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $count;
//Table header
echo "<div><table id=\"tableheader\" bgcolor=\"#4382b5\">\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;3-4 ID:</td>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;First Name:</td>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;Last Name:</td>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;HCA:</td>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;File:</td>\n";
echo "<tr>";
echo "</table></div>";
if ($count !== 0) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<div class=\"addform\"><form method='get' action=\"update.php\">\n";
                echo "  <input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['tfid']."\" name=\"column1\">\n";
                echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"column2\" value=\"".$row['fname']."\"/>\n";
                echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"column3\" value=\"".$row['lname']."\"/>\n";
                echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"column4\" value=\"".$row['hca']."\"/>\n";
                echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"column5\" value=\"".$row['file']."\"/>\n";
                echo "  <input type=\"image\" src=\"images/update.png\" alt=\"Update Row\" class=\"update\" title=\"Update Row\">\n";
                echo "<a href=\"delete.php?tfid=".$row['tfid']."\"><img title='Delete Row' alt=\"Delete\" class='del' src='images/delete.png'/></a></form></div>\n";

            }
        echo "</table><br />\n";
    } else {
        echo "<b><center>NO DATA</center></b>\n";
    }
```

Comment: what are you getting for `echo $count;` ?

Comment: How are you obtaining data from DB ? PHP code seems fine, you can have incorrect SQL.

Comment: Please post (relevant) code blocks directly inside your question.

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and guess that you're doing some sort of cross `JOIN` in your SQL query which multiplies the result.

Comment: the result for echo $count; is 9.
echo $result returns Resource id #6 (for some reason).

Comment: give us the query that you are hitting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Comment: the query is:
   <pre> query = "SELECT staff.tfid, staff.lname, staff.fname,     staff.hca, pic.file ".
     "FROM staff, pic";<code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your latest comment:

```
SELECT staff.tfid, staff.lname, staff.fname, staff.hca, pic.file ". "FROM staff, pic
```

you are using 2 tables `staff` and `pic`. But you do not have any joining criteria. You should have something like `staff.id=pic.id`

That is why you are getting ***Cartesian product*** of the two result-set i.e. squared result-set. 4 for `staff` table multiplied by 4 for `pic` table

Your  query should be :

```
SELECT staff.tfid, staff.lname, staff.fname, staff.hca, pic.file ". " 
FROM staff, pic
where staff.id=pic.id
```

considering you have `id` as related attribute between these 2 tables.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I really appreciate it. By the way, I am seeing my question being down-voted and I have no idea why. Could someone tell me the reason for this? I think I asked a legitimate question.

Comment: @kayle: there are several reasons why downvotes are given. The first thing to note is, don't worry about it, and keep posting! Votes are only guidance and not intended to offend. In this case, it could have been: (a) an external link to code was provided rather than including code here, which can give rise to _link rot_, (b) not providing the SQL in your code example, which would force someone to ask for it, (c) posting here even though you feel you should have done some more research first, (d) not debugging the problem.